# Exported Module Returning Object Promise -- calling fs.readFile as a module

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node.js-fs

I wrote a simple module that reads a file called `readHistory.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');


async function readHistory(history){
    fs.readFile("history_file.txt", function read(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

    const myRAM = data.toString();
    history = myRAM;
    //console.log(myRAM); 
    });
};
readHistory();
module.exports = { readHistory }
```

I import it to a different module like so:

```
const { readHistory } = require("./readHistory")
```

Then I try to get the value like this:

```
const contextClues = Promise.resolve(readHistory(myRAM));
```

Which returns:

```
 [object Promise]
```

I also tried like this:

```
const contextClues = Promise.resolve(readHistory(myRAM));    
contextClues.then((value) => {
    console.log("Other context: " + value)
})
```

Which returned `Undefined`.

I've tried a bunch of different permutations on the above so I'm starting to think the problem is in `ReadHistory.js`.

I've tried putting my expression inside an async function and using await:

```
const contextClues = await Promise.resolve(readHistory(myRAM))
```

And that returns `Undefined` which I think is worse. I've tried writing the function with and without an argument and it doesn't seem to matter. To be honest the argument is an artifact from when I tried writing it as a callback but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a reading of a file to a separate module could be simplified with 1 line:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const history = fs.readFileSync('history_file.txt').toString();
```

Comment: I have a freshly upgraded node. I've been out of the game for a while but my environment is up-to-date. I've been getting up on ES Modules but I'm still more familiar with the CommonJS way for right now. 

The readfile script works on its own, it just doesnt work when I call it from the other module

Comment: @Z-ManJones sorry man, your code doesn't make sense. It just wrong JS.
I'm adding code how to make it in a module

Comment: It's part of a much larger file and I tried to trim it down to only the relevant parts. Maybe I overedited

Comment: As you see you just move 1 code line to a module. For me it doesn't much improve the situation...

Comment: Even with those solutions, I still don't see how I extract the value from the readfile to perform operations

Comment: `const history = fs.readFileSync('history_file.txt').toString();` - the simplest solution

Comment: That is....easy. Thank you. This was overengineered. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it solved.

Comment: @Z-ManJones done and good luck with your project!